# Effective way to create .csv file from MongoDB

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb

I have a MongoDB(`media_mongo`) with collection `main_hikari` and a lot of data inside. I'm trying to make a function to create a `.csv` file from this data asap. I'm using this code, but it takes too much time and CPU usage

```py
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient



mongo_client = MongoClient('mongodb://admin:password@localhost:27017')
db = mongo_client.media_mongo


def download_file(down_file_name="hikari"):
    docs = pd.DataFrame(columns=[])
    if down_file_name == "kokyaku":
        col = db.main_kokyaku
    if down_file_name == "hikari":
        col = db.main_hikari
    if down_file_name == "hikanshou":
        col = db.main_hikanshou

    cursor = col.find()
    mongo_docs = list(cursor)
    for num, doc in enumerate(mongo_docs):
        doc["_id"] = str(doc["_id"])
        doc_id = doc["_id"]
        series_obj = pandas.Series(doc, name=doc_id)
        docs = docs.append(series_obj)


    csv_export = docs.to_csv("file.csv", sep=",")

download_file()
```

My database has data in this format (sorry for that Japanese :D)

```
_id:"ObjectId("5e0544c4f4eefce9ee9b5a8b")"
事業者受付番号:"data1"
開通区分/処理区分:"data2"
開通ST/処理ST:"data3"
申込日,顧客名:"data4"
郵便番号:"data5"
住所1:"data6"
住所2:"data7"
連絡先番号:"data8"
契約者電話番号:"data9"
```

And about 150000 entries like this

Comment: And With pySpark?

Comment: have never used it, could you please tell me more?

Comment: https://medium.com/@manishpal/create-spark-rdd-for-mongodb-collection-in-python-b985b917ea01

Comment: You can export a MongoDB collection to a CSV file using [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/index.html) command line tool (runs from os prompt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a lot of data as you indicate, then this line is going to hurt you:

```
    mongo_docs = list(cursor)
```

It basically means read the **entire** collection into a client-side array at once.  This will create a huge memory high water mark.

Better to use `mongoexport` as noted above or walk the cursor yourself instead of having `list()` slurp the whole thing, e.g.:

```
cursor = col.find()
for doc in cursor:
    # read docs one at a time
```

or to be very pythonic about it:

```
for doc in col.find():  # or find(expression of your choice)
    # read docs one at a time
```